# getting key, value of 'this': what would be equivalent jQuery for javascript?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to re-write the following using `$(this)` instead of `this` (without needing any additional information)? If yes, then what would it look like?

```
 $.each(this, function(key,value){
    alert(key + " " + value);
 })
```

---

Background: this is what the overall program looks like:

```
var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };

$.each(data.programs, function(i){

     $.each(this, function(key,value){
        alert(key + " " + value);
     })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just store the `$(this)` into a variable and use the variable in the `$.each` and it'll work the same as your first `$.each` or you could use a simple `for loop` instead of using a second '$.each'.

Two examples of how you could do this:

```js
var data = { "programs": [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" } ] };

$.each(data.programs, function(i)
{
     var dataPrograms = $(this);
     $.each(dataPrograms[0], function(key, value)
     {
       console.log("JQUERY: [KEY]" + key + " " + "[VALUE]" + value);
     })
});

$.each(data.programs, function(i)
{
     var dataPrograms = $(this);
  
     for (i = 0; i < dataPrograms.length; i++) 
     { 
       console.log("NAME: " + dataPrograms[i].name);
       console.log("PRICE: " + dataPrograms[i].price);
     }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, `console.log(value.name);` gives me only the values of the `name` keys. My original code alerts each key and the value as a pair (including the `price` keys).

Comment: @user1883050 - You're correct and the correct I've provided was just example code, show you how you can check through them and how you can grab the properties of each value. So for example `value.name` would give the value of name `value.price` would give you the value of price. Then if you console.log out `value` then it would give you both name and price.

Comment: I have a follow up question (mostly out of curiosity). I tried using `$(this)[0]` instead of `dataPrograms[0]`, and that worked too. I then tried `$(this).0`, why didn't that work? After all, `$(this)` is an object, and `0` is a key inside the object (I confirmed that by doing a `console.log`).

Comment: @user1883050 When a Javascript object property's name doesn't begin with either an underscore or a letter, you cant use the dot notation (`$(this).0`), and you must use the alternative notation, which is `$(this)[0].

Comment: @user1883050 Yes there is :) - Good luck with everything.